# Can not set height of ion-img without using inline styles in Ionic 5

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

Updating my Angular project from Ionic 3 to Ionic 5.

Formerly I had an `<img>` logo element inside `<ion-navbar>`. On which I could simply apply a `.logo` CSS selector.

Now I am trying to achieve the same with `<ion-img>` inside `<ion-title>` inside `<ion-toolbar>`.

But no matter what I try, I can not add CSS to the ion-img element. It seems to not accept any CSS class either.

already tried to wrap the CSS file with `:host {}`

Answer (score 0):

Turned out styles were not working at all.

After adding `/styles/styles.scss` and adding `@import 'src/app/app.component.scss';` to it, it started working.

Also added

```
{
   "input": "src/styles/styles.scss"
}
```

to `styles` in `angular.json`.

Styling a component works as expected again.